# How can I access the numbers in a String?

Tags: c#

```
string sequence = "12345";
int[] ziffern = new int[sequence.Count()];
for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Count(); i++)
{
    ziffern[i] =  Convert.ToInt32(sequence.ElementAt(i));
}
```

It does not work like that. How can I access every single number?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? And what do you mean by access every single number?

Comment: I want to store the `1`, `2` etc in an array. But like I did it above it does not work.

Comment: I voted up your question because I had fun with it and to be nice to a new user... so you'll get a couple extra points!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ElementAt` will return a `char`.

When you convert a `char` to an `Int32`, you will get the **ASCII code** of the character.

Try this:

```
 string sequence = "12345";
 int[] ziffern = new int[sequence.Length];
 for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length; i++)
 {
       ziffern[i] = Convert.ToInt32(sequence.Substring(i, 1));
 }
```

Comment: I wanted to vote you up, but infortunately I can't because I haven't enough reputation yet sry.

Comment: Great to hear. On stack overflow, if an answer works for you, it is considered good practice to accept it as the correct answer so anyone searching for it in future can find it quicker.

Comment: A better choice than `Convert.ToInt32()` would be `Int32.Parse(sequence[i].ToString())` -- the former actually calls `Int32.Parse` anyway, thus it is faster to call directly. The syntax `sequence[i].ToString()` is the same as `sequence.Substring(i, 1)` but is also faster. Using `Int32.Parse` opens you to exceptions occurring if a non-digit is in your sequence. See my answer which uses `Int32.TryParse` if this could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You mean 'every single digit'?

```
string sequence = "12345";
int[] ziffern = new int[sequence.Length];
int idx = 0;
foreach (char c in sequence)
{
    if (int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out ziffern[idx])) idx++;
}
// idx contains # of valid digits found
```

See `Int32.TryParse(string, out int)` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sequence.Length` instead of `Count()` extension method. Both `string` and `int[]` have this property.

A string is actually equivalent to `char[]`, so use it.

```
string sequence = "12345";
int[] ziffern = new int[sequence.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length; i++)
{
    ziffern[i] =  Convert.ToInt32(sequence[i]);
}
```

Comment: This wrongly returns ASCII codes. You need `sequence[i].ToString()` to convert the `char` to a `string`. Also, use `Int32.Parse()` or `Int32.TryParse()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()` which ends up calling `Int32.Parse()` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You used GetNumericValue method (Convert.ToInt32) which converts a Char object that represents a number to a numeric value type. Therefore its the ASCII code that is returned from that method. Use Parse and TryParse to convert a character in a string into a Char object. Use ToString to convert a Char object to a String object.
 Try this:

```
string sequence = "12345";
int[] ziffern = new int[sequence.Count()];
int bar;
for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Count(); i++)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(sequence.ElementAt(i).ToString(), out bar))
    {
    //Do something to correct the problem
    }
    else
    {
       ziffern[i] =  bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: This needlessly relies on LINQ. The `string` class does not contain a `Count()` method or `ElementAt()` method, but DOES contain the `Length` property and the default item property `sequence[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Linq solution to turning it into an `int[]` also:

```
    public int[] ExtractNumbers(string numbers)
    {
        return numbers
            .ToCharArray()
            .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)))
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = new int[sequence.Length];

for(int i=0; i<sequence.Length; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(sequence[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: In this code `sequence[i]` returns a `char` which invokes `Convert.ToInt32(char)` which returns an ASCII code, NOT the numeric value! You need to write `sequence[i].ToString()` instead which invokes `Convert.ToInt32(string)`.

Comment: No worries. I had to test and update my answer too! :) I'd rather comment than vote down.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ does this nicely:

```
string sequence = "12345";
var ziffern = sequence.Select(c => (int)(c - '0')).ToArray();
```

Alternatively you could use the `Char.GetNumericValue(char c)` method in there, which would also handle characters like ⅓ in the string.

Comment: I love playing with the LINQ syntax, but I would not use the minus operator for converting ASCII to value. It's just going to open you up to negative return values and it obfuscates the purpose. Use `Int32.Parse()` or `Int32.TryParse()`. I don't think I would use LINQ on this problem either. Not totally positive, but I'm pretty sure a simple loop boils down to tighter and faster code. Maybe not after compiler optimization, but I feel that using LINQ because you can isn't always the way to go.

Comment: @KevinP.Rice Agreed. In reality I would refactor into an extension method and include some validation. If performance is important, I would measure different approaches to find the fastest.

Comment: You've made me curious how LINQ compares after all the compiler optimizations happen. There's some really creative LINQ suggestions at times that would truly invoke some pretty heavy resources compared to a plain and boring loop. I'm not sure your code does that... but I don't know what type of container is instantiated which is then converted to an array. Populating an array in the first place (I'm pretty sure) would be faster and involve fewer resources. I avoid LINQ unless it's the best-fit solution. Also LINQ requires .NET 3.5 which adds another requirement to your code.

Comment: @KevinP.Rice Sounds like you're overthinking a little! It's unlikely that this will be used with huge strings so we're aiming for clean code that works. Good point about the container - I know `Select` returns `IEnumerable<char>` but I'm not sure what's going on under the hood. Maybe a linked list? Let me know if you find out.

Comment: Best I can find is `Select` returns a concrete private type called `System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIterator<T>`. I'd guess this is a `char` iterator for the `sequence` string. Building this iterator requires overhead. Also, remember LINQ execution is deferred and there is some overhead for that feature. All in all, LINQ is only slightly slower, but I avoid it if the only purpose is compacting three lines to one. I might replace your LINQ with `sequence.Select(c => Int32.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray()` which will PROPERLY throw an exception for non-digit chars & avoids char subtraction.